# How to write python code in HTML in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need to create a path in an HTML code that is used to generate a download link.

```
   {% for data in all_data %}
   {% path_zip = '/home/harish/Desktop/cvision/users_output_files/{0}.zip'.format(data.id) %}
      <tr>
          <td> {{data.id}} </td>
          <td> {{data.childname}} </td>
          <td> {{data.age}} </td>
          <td> {{data.gender}} </td>
          <td> <a href={{path_zip}} download></a> </td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

But this code is not working. And the following is the error.

```
Invalid block tag on line 40: 'path_zip', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: The absolute path here is really a big problem, will it work for other users too?

Comment: Right now I just need to test it on my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant, and dont need to write python here, you could use   a custom template tag but it would be overkill, just insert the value like you did the others

```
<td> <a href="/home/harish/Desktop/cvision/users_output_files/{{data.id}}.zip" download></a>
```

Comment: This is what I need to create as a link:  href="/home/harish/Desktop/cvision/users_output_files/'{{data.id}}'/'{{data.id}}'.zip'" But it didn't work

Comment: That's fine, just remove the single quotes.